# Methane emission free satellite imagery for seminar finals?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, environment

I am looking for a downloadable satellite imagery that provides methane emission data in the Middle East region (Jordan, Israel, Egypt, Lebanon and Syria). So far I have not been able to find any service or satellite with information open to the public. Next I plan to perform analyzes in the ENVI \ ERDAS program in order to make adjustments against the existing imagery. I would be happy to receive a reference to reliable sources.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest approach would be to simply use the methane product from the Sentinel 5 satellites.
Data access and search can be done here:
https://s5phub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home
From there, it is just a matter of downloading and analyzing the data.